# Linked list program not giving expected result

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to set head -> data =10 and then add 10 values (101-110) in the beginning of  linked list.

Currently I am getting **Output: 10**

Can someone help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node *next;
};
void main()
{
 struct node *head, emp;
 int num = 10, i;
 void add_beg(struct node *q, int n);
 void traverse(struct node *q);
 clrscr();
 head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 head->data = num;
 head->next = NULL;
 for (i= 101; i<=110; i++)
 {
  add_beg(head, i);
 }

 traverse(head);
 getch();

}

void add_beg(struct node *q, int num)
{
 int n = num;
 struct node *temp;
 temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
 temp->data = n;
 temp->next = q;
 q = temp;
}

void traverse(struct node *q)
{
while(q!=NULL)
  {
   printf("%d\n",q->data);
   q = q->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not declare function prototypes inside the `main()` body, it's ugly and confusing.

Comment: Please take the time to digest the answers you got in your previous question, the `q=temp` in `add_beg` looks very suspicious.

Comment: what is pointing to **last** element? Theres only pointing **next**

Comment: @Mat Yes, it helped me solving the issue!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `void add_beg(struct node *q, int num)` to `void add_beg(struct node **q, int num)`.

The pointer passed cannot be changed, I mean the actual address is copied and won't change outside of add_beg(), the pointed to value can be changed. So if you have a pointer to a pointer, you can change the pointed to pointer (head).

So to get the head back to your main function you will need to call it like this `add_beg(&head, i);` with the aforementioned change to add_beg().

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *head* winds up being at the end of the list, so when you traverse from *head*, *head*'s value is printed and traverse() stops since *head->next* is null.

You can try having add_beg() return the *temp* pointer, and use the final value returned by add_beg() for your call to traverse().